# Debugging /loading bluestacks from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bluestacks

Why wont the bluestacks App player show up in my device manager list when I try run an app that I am developing in eclipse

the bluestacks App player is running so it should be available.
I am using windows 7.

[image: bluestacks App player device manager]

Comment: Same thing happened with me too.

Comment: is ur bluestack shown in device windoe in eclipse????

Comment: no it isnt   .............

Comment: The solution below worked for me.  @Hello-World, if it worked for you, you should accept.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Connect your bluestack as below :

1. Open cmd
2. go to android sdk path
3. Example : E:/Android/Android/sdk/
4. open platform-tools folder as : E:/Android/Android/sdk/platform-tools
5. connect your blustack with command as:

   adb connect localhost
   OR
   adb connect localhost:5555

you can also try this: adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555

Comment: when I do this it says successfully connected to localhost 5555
but still problem is not solved.

Comment: can u plz explain in details what happening now?

Comment: this is my question's/problem's link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097517/eclipse-find-bluestack-but-cant-use-as-emulator?noredirect=1#comment39054209_25097517

Comment: after trying above steps if still you cannot see bluestack in ddms , reset adb from ddms ..

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `adb devices` in my Terminal, it restarted ADB and Eclipse was able to see Bluestacks.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps:

- Copy the hd-apk handler from c:/programs files/bluestacks or what ever is yours and paste it on desktop
- Copy your apk file and paste it on the desktop
- Now drag your apkfile right into the hd-apk handler
- Now it will install your apk file