# eclipse find bluestack but can't use as emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, bluestacks

I recently started to learn android app developing and I'm using eclipse. I want to use Bluestacks as android virtual device. When I check for devices in eclipse it shows blustacks 
[image]

but when I run the app it says

> No active compatible AVD's or devices found.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: The steps provided here may help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551664/debugging-loading-bluestacks-from-eclipse

Comment: this link was promising but don't work :/

Comment: hmm  got it can u come on stackoverflow chat?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you need Bluestack always download from **www.bluestacks.com/**
   since bluestack comes up which newest version ..and downloading from
   other sites may lead u with older version of bluestack ect and hence
   you are stuck with bluestack verison issue .
2. Make sure there is icon in task bar and Quit first and restart once
   bluestack installed .
   [image]
3. You can get all bluestack Info at blow steps :

--> type **regedit** in windows search

Below Image shows u meta data for ur bluestack can u can also find verison of blestack , and provide custom location for ur bluestack for sdcard etc.

[image]